# Distributed TF: multi-PS version LR doesn't converge

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built a custom LR model which supports sparse feature vector with the following code:

```
    def custom_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
        linear_bias = tf.get_variable(name='linear_bias',
                                      shape=[1],
                                      dtype=tf.float32,
                                      initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.0001))

        linear_w = tf.get_variable(name='linear_w',
                                   shape=[params['feature_size'], 1],
                                   dtype=tf.float32,
                                   initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.0001),
                                   partitioner=self.partitioner)

        # wx
        # size: [batch_size, 1]
        logits_wide = tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse(params=linear_w,
                                                    sp_ids=features['featureID'],
                                                    sp_weights=None,
                                                    combiner='sum')
        # wx + b
        logits = linear_bias + logits_wide

        logits_adjusted = logits + tf.math.log(params['negative_sampling_rate'])

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            predictions = {
                'probabilities': tf.nn.sigmoid(logits_adjusted),
                'logits': logits,
                'logits_adjusted': logits_adjusted
            }

            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

        else:
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.float32),
                                                        logits=logits))

            if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
                auc = tf.metrics.auc(
                    labels=labels,
                    predictions=1 / (1 + tf.math.exp(-logits_adjusted)),
                    num_thresholds=400,
                    curve='ROC',
                    summation_method='careful_interpolation')
                logloss = tf.metrics.mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                    labels=tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.float32),
                    logits=logits_adjusted))
                tf.summary.scalar('True_AUC', auc)
                tf.summary.scalar('True_Logloss', logloss)
                metrics = {
                    'True_AUC': auc,
                    'True_Logloss': logloss
                }

                predictions = {
                    'probabilities': tf.nn.sigmoid(logits_adjusted),
                    'logits': logits,
                    'logits_adjusted': logits_adjusted
                }

                return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, predictions=predictions,
                                                  eval_metric_ops=metrics)

            elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
                train_op = self.optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

                return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

The partitioner I used is tf.fixed_size_partitioner with number of ps as the parameter. When I run this code with only one PS, I got auc=0.87 which was correct. However, when I used multiple ps (ps_num > 1), I always got auc=0.5. I have checked the graph, the partitioner successfully distributed linear_w among PS. Also the global_step went up to 30,000+ which also suggested the optimizer was working. Is there anything I missed in distributed TF to cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep code identical in train and evaluate. It means that you need to use `tf.get_variable(xxx,parititioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(6))` even if on single worker, the number 6 depends on how many you used in train.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have realized this requirement and always used the same ps number of training process during separate evaluation. However i still don't get why I have to do this druing evaluation. I check the checkpoint file and the partitioned variables have indices which i think could be used to order and merge them into a whole variable for further use. But directly loading and restoring checkpoint without ps number would fail...